# How to send AHD video wirelessly to an Android device (short range ~3m)?

Tags: video, android

I have an underwater camera (wired to the water surface) which streams AHD digital video to a RG59 connector.
I would like be able to stream the video to an Android device.

It doesn't have to be a wireless stream, but it would be better (I was thinking about wireless because of so many FPV systems, but I have no idea about the AHD protocol and its limits).

I have no preference: WiFi, hotspot, Bluetooth... (also wired as I said).

The only needs I have is 12 V hardware (because of the boat's limits) and
as little hardware as possible (for the same reason).

(Explanations about AHD video transmission are welcome.)

Comment: How much electronics design you are willing to make to do what you want?

Comment: If you do not know how to build video hardware, WiFi hardware, and program Android drivers and video playing software, this isn't happening. Home-built FPV systems use analog video for this reason because android and digital is not workable. Really, the only reason analog is workable is there are only two standards: PAL and NTSC. You still need to buy everything premade. The only way digital video it is happening is if you buy a system that already does it (either special purpose digital FPV which may require replacing the camera, or using consumer PC webcams and WiFi routers).

Comment: @justme, I did some little electronic for arduino and raspberry. clearly I was looking for some given hardware (converter, adapter or similar). but If I have to do a little job I can try. Surelly I don't have great electronic skills. (tank you)

Comment: If you are asking what to buy, that's off topic.

Comment: understood. but otherwise if I ask for tecnology explanation and how can I realize that? (i'm not forcing you to answer me)